# How do you use componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate in a BaseWebPart class?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

Someone told me that he was using `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` in his `BaseWebPart` class, but looking at the documentation below I realized it shouldn't be possible since it's not a React Component.

[BaseWebPart class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-webpart-base/basewebpart?view=sp-typescript-latest)

Is there something I am missing, what do you need to do in order to be able to use `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`? Or is it possible that there was some kind of misunderstanding and he did not use `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` in his `BaseWebPart` class. Is it also best practice to use `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` instead of the `onInit` provided by the `BaseWebPart` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BaseWebPart` class is something comes with [@microsoft/sp-webpart-base package](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-webpart-base) and `componentDidMount` & `componentDidUpdate` are methods of [The Component Lifecycle of React](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

These are not related at all. So, you cannot write `componentDidMount` & `componentDidUpdate` methods in `BaseWebPart` class.

However if you want to use the React components in your SPFx webpart then you need to import the dependencies. Check below documentation on how to use it:

[HOW TO GET STARTED WITH REACT FOR BUILDING ADVANCED SPFX SOLUTIONS](https://laurakokkarinen.com/how-to-get-started-with-react-for-building-advanced-spfx-solutions/).

Answer (score 2):

You are right. It is not possible, nor wanted to use any React component lifecycle in `BaseWebPart`.